# Buttons in a SlidingDrawer

Tags: android, focus, slidingdrawer

In my android app, I'd like to put buttons in the handle of a SlidingDrawer.

1) Do you think it's correct from a design point of view ?

2) How do I prevent the buttons to get focus when the handle is dragged ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Don't care. Just do it.

2) Overriding SlidingDrawer's onTouch to prevent focus on UIs laid out in the handle. Then pass down touch event to appropriate UI for particular function you want to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Try next widget 
https://github.com/xPutnikx/SlidingDrawerWithButtons

make it left to right, or another directions. It is also possible to add a few buttons in the handler